# jquery listeners conflict

Tags: jquery, listener

Rule 1: on click event of span id="B"
        sets the value of input box id=A to the text value of Div B.

Rule 2: on blur event of text input box id="A"
        set the value of div B to blanks

When I click on A, then B, B is erased before the value of B is copied to A
Is there a way to influence order of jQuery listeners?

I would like the click event to take presidence over the blur event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add your clean code into setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //Clean 
}, 10);
```

it should do it

Comment: you may have to vary the ms, as different browsers/setups may require differen  delay.